Difference in Textbooks and Books from "Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese"?
What is the difference between the sections Textbooks and Books from the Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese post? I believe there is some confusion between the sections.

Just by the way: the post is over 8 years old and it does get periodically edited by different users.

I find that page mostly pointless: it's basically "here's every resource, regardless of usefulness" and is poorly maintained.  I went through them at one point, and found broken links, referral codes, etc.  I made What resources do you actively use to study Chinese, and why? as an alternative, but it hasn't caught on.

Yeah, I also found it quite difficult to search for relevant material, as they are ordered alphabetically instead of their "usefulness". Maybe it would be better to have a page for every type of resource like Books, Apps, Audiobooks, etc. And just post every resource as an answer, then they can be voted and most useful resources would appear first? I think that would be quite useful for this site...

I feel determining usefulness based on voting will simply indicate the Chinese level of the userbase.  Moreover, these votes become obsolete, and users won't subsequently modify their votes accordingly.

I don't think good resources become obsolete. If that was the case though, the post could be updated every few years (like indicating the year of the poll in the post) copying all the answers of the previous years and letting people vote again. Also, it could be specified the Chinese level of the resource as well. I believe just knowing which resources are more popular can be quite helpful.

I edited it, so the distinction should be clearer now.  However, maybe it's worth merging the Books and Textbooks answers.
